# Upgrading SVN 1.4 to 1.5.3 and CC.Net from 1.3 to 1.4

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I think this is a multi-part question, so bear with me.

Currently all of our developers use the version of Tortise built for SVN 1.4 and our SVN server is running 1.4. Our build server is running CC.Net and is using SVN 1.4.

We want to upgrade.

I've established that upgrading our clients to 1.5, then our server to 1.5 will work for us. However, the question comes in with CC.Net. Can we just upgrade the install of SVN on our build server to SVN 1.5? Or do we have to upgrade the install of CC.Net too? We'd like to also take this time to upgrade CC.Net, however, we'd like to make sure the SVN upgrade is done first, then come back and do CC.Net.

Also adding to this mix is that in some of our projects we maintain a 'tools' folder that may or may not contain the binaries for SVN due to the nAnt scripts we use in those projects. I assume that if we upgrade the CC.Net server install of SVN to 1.5, we'll also need to update all of those projects as the CI server uses the same working directory as the nAnt scripts that get executed.

clear as mud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to answer as it seems you're asking for a plan for your environment, which I'm not in.

However, here's what I'd do:

- Upgrade cc.net (you have a known good starting point, and this is the most likely breaking step.  do it without any other variables so it is easier to roll back)
- Test & Verify
- Upgrade all the svn clients including the binaries in your "tools" folder
- Test & Verify
- Upgrade the svn server
- Test & Verify
- Test & Verify

Answer (score 1):

A little tip that may help you: SVN 1.4 clients can connect to a SVN 1.5 server, and SVN 1.5 clients can connect to a SVN 1.4 server, no problems -- just when you have a version mismatch, some of the newly added SVN features will not be available (but all the normal stuff will still work fine).